# .htaccess: Redirect / to index.php and block everything else

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to protect my PHP files against direct access. What I want to allow is direct access to `index.php` and a directory called `public` (with CSS, Images, etc.). Access to the root directory `/` should redirect to `index.php`:

```
/ (root): allow -> redirect to index.php
+--index.php: allow
+--public
|  +--... allow
+--[everything else]: block
```

My current `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
order allow,deny
<Files index.php>
  Allow from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It basically works but won't redirect from `/` to `index.php`, instead Apache is giving me a 403 error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `Order ...`, which you can find [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order).

> **Allow,Deny**
>
> > First, all Allow directives are evaluated; at least one must match, or
> >     the request is rejected. Next, all Deny directives are evaluated. If
> >     any matches, the request is rejected. Last, any requests which do not
> >     match an Allow or a Deny directive are denied by default.

The request for `/` does not match any rules, so there are no allow or deny directives for it, so it is denied by default. You fix it by explicitly allowing a request to `/`, and creating a new .htaccess file in the public subdirectory to allow requests there.

---

In `/.htaccess`:

```
order allow,deny
<Files ~ "^(index\.php|)$">
  Allow from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

And in `/public/.htaccess`:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Screencast of this working: https://www.screenr.com/BLfN

Comment: I am using your suggested configuration except that I changed the order from `Allow,Deny` to `Deny,Allow` in `/.htaccess`. Also added `Options -Indexes` to prevent directory listings and now it works perfectly. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Then you won't need the first `<Files>` block, and it won't block anything but .htaccess at that point.

Comment: I notice that mod_rewrite is not needed here, so I've edited that out. It is already handled by the directoryindex

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the Allow/Deny order, didn't see that at first. Thanks for clearing out the rewrite config. Now it really works ;-)